# how to build corona sdk for android?

Tags: coronasdk

hi friends any one him help to me solve this problem in corona sdk
   i have account in indie android when i build.when i build for for android os they make question

1. continue trial
2. verify purchase
3. upgrade

i will choose a 2nd(verify purchase) option. And they show build window. In that window I'll fill the application,version code,package,and when browse a keystore  file .And they make again the same question above and i again choose the verify purchase .And it does not give permission to choose keystore .and it automatically select the default keystore file.
And it build app as trial users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a verification issue that you will need to file a support ticket to resolve. If you have changed your email address or password that may have caused the issue.

You can contact support here: http://developer.coronalabs.com/forms/support

Someone will be able to assist you from there - alternatively if you have changed your email or password temporarily changing it back may provide a temporary solution while this is being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If its a verification issue you could also try to deauthorize your computer in Corona SDK: Corona Simulator -> Preferences->Deauthorize and Quit

or delete these in ~/library/Preferences/ folder.
com.anscamobile.ratatouille.plist
com.anscamobile.Corona_Simulator.plist